# jQuery bounce variation (bounce around)

Tags: jquery, bounce

I'm struggling to find an addon/plugin for this and its a key part of my project that ive overlooked and now its bitten me.

I need a variation of jQuery bounce which makes a div bounce around a parent div/wrapper indefinately.

Effectively I'll be having a screen which users spawn div's by clicking and they float/bounce around the screen.

please help direct me to a plugin or some code that will solve this issue for me.

many thanks

Comment: okay - i found someone here on stackoverflow who wrote a very similar piece of code that i've adapted. however when it animates it shakes, can anybody resolve this? http://jsfiddle.net/OwenMelbz/jgJsL/2/

Comment: It doesn't actually "shake". It bounces of the side walls which are just a bit to close together for this example. Try changing the width of the container and you'll see what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/jgJsL/3/ — The code in this example could use some serious tweaking, though to make it usable in a more general way.

Comment: okay i understand, what do you think will be a better approach to achieve what i need? especially as i noticed as soon as there are more than 1 <li> they go crazy and get stuck in their own little corners?

Comment: You just want a div bounce off all four "walls"?

Comment: every div to bounce of the container, there will be like 100 divs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't tell you how responsive this will be with a 100 divs, but based on the earlier script here's something to get you at least started — http://jsfiddle.net/jgJsL/5/:

```
$.fn.bounce = function(options) {

    var settings = $.extend({
        speed: 10
    }, options);

    return $(this).each(function() {

        var $this = $(this),
            $parent = $this.parent(),
            height = $parent.height(),
            width = $parent.width(),
            top = Math.floor(Math.random() * (height / 2)) + height / 4,
            left = Math.floor(Math.random() * (width / 2)) + width / 4,
            vectorX = settings.speed * (Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1 : -1),
            vectorY = settings.speed * (Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1 : -1);

        // place initialy in a random location
        $this.css({
            'top': top,
            'left': left
        }).data('vector', {
            'x': vectorX,
            'y': vectorY
        });

        var move = function($e) {

            var offset = $e.offset(),
                width = $e.width(),
                height = $e.height(),
                vector = $e.data('vector'),
                $parent = $e.parent();

            if (offset.left <= 0 && vector.x < 0) {
                vector.x = -1 * vector.x;
            }
            if ((offset.left + width) >= $parent.width()) {
                vector.x = -1 * vector.x;
            }
            if (offset.top <= 0 && vector.y < 0) {
                vector.y = -1 * vector.y;
            }
            if ((offset.top + height) >= $parent.height()) {
                vector.y = -1 * vector.y;
            }

            $e.css({
                'top': offset.top + vector.y + 'px',
                'left': offset.left + vector.x + 'px'
            }).data('vector', {
                'x': vector.x,
                'y': vector.y
            });

            setTimeout(function() {
                move($e);
            }, 50);

        };

        move($this);
    });

};

$(function() {
    $('#wrapper li').bounce({
        'speed': 7
    });
});
```

Comment: @polarblau this is great. I'm new to jquery and trying to figure out  way to add rotation to the balls. Make them spin  360 degrees clock wise or counter clockwise randomly when they hit the edge of the parent element.

Comment: @polarblau Hey, this is cool peace of code! Any idea how to make it also bounce  hitting balls not just walls?